# BIRT beforeOpen method gets new HttpSession object

Tags: java, session, birt

I have a Java EE web application (webapp1) with BIRT 3.7.1 integrated. We have few reports and one of the report params is hidden and the value is fetched implicitly from session object.This is done by using scripted dataset and below is the single line used to map the hidden input param of report to the session attribute. Below is the snippet of code from BIRT logs. This works great in webapp1.

beforeOpen() {
inputParams["param_6"] =(String)(reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("AppKey"));
}

Now I am integrating the same reports in another web application (webapp2). The above report which worked fine in webapp1, is not able to find the session attribute in webapp2. I debugged and saw that the session id in the cookie while accessing BIRT's frameset servlet is the same as the web application session. I am not able to understand why BIRT is not able to get the same session where the session attribute was set. The session attribute is set in a JSP page of the web application 2.

BIRT integration above is nothing but embedding all the BIRT files/folders in the web application. This is same as the BIRT runtime sample. The web container being used in Tomcat7.

Comment: So you have included a BIRT runtime both in webapp1 and webapp2, right? Can you confirm with something like "psi probe" that your attribute is correctly set in Tomcat sessions of webapp2? Furthermore, since you have 2 BIRT engines working on a same JVM, they probably make use of the same temporary folder [tomcat_home]/temp. This *might* cause caching issues, leading to this kind of side-effect: try to set a different name for the report design in webapp2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. webapp1 and webapp2 don't co-exist on same jvm. I am planning to probe the session as next step. Will update once I have found something. Initially session id was changing when I accessed BIRT servlet compared to other URLs in app. That was a good reason for why I couldn't see the session attribute. Now that I have fixed it, I need to find out why I still can't access session attributes under same session.

Comment: I used the PSI Probe and it turned out to be a trivial issue but the one difficult to catch. There was a case issue in the session attribute key name "Appkey" instead of "AppKey". Once webapp2 was corrected to set with correct case, the issue got resolved.